# Multiple SabreCommandLLSRQ HostCommands

Tags: sabre, sabredav

Anyone know how to send multiple chained commands via SabreCommandLLSRQ HostCommand?
I'm trying to avoid the network back and forward (gets slow when you need 50 commands to get one full page)

Ex:
**FQYYZBKK15JAN-AC** + all the necessary move downs, or get the fare rules for all the 99 or so fares there.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to scrape all available Fares + the attributes (penalties, baggage etc). I cant clarify because of my reputation.

If so you might be better of with Vayant or some caching company of Fares as it is way cheaper (you are producing tons of looks but no books and might brake the limit (look/book) that has been agreed upon with sabre.

If you want to stay with sabre you should use: FareLLSRQ also called Air Fare by City Pairs + OTA_AirRulesLLSRQ

Comment: That is correct, need to show the baggage info, penalties and so on at a glance. 

Cannot use OTA_AirRulesLLSRQ since it's still one request per fare.

We also have private fares, I'm not sure if hose come loaded in Vayant, do they?

Comment: You can get them loaded in Vayant aswell (this you have to agree on with your farefiler). But you can also easily parallelize the OTA_AirRulesLLSRQ because they are basicly stateless which is note the case with SabreCommandLLSRQ

Comment: Do you have any idea how often those fare rules change?

Comment: Out of my experience for the attributes you are looking at hardly (1 once a year) to never - the carrier here in europe usally take a new "Farebase". But again - make sure your look to book stays within your contract otherwise this is gonna become a mighty expensive experience

Comment: Two fallow ups: any idea how many total fares are there in the world? / any place to get a dump every X days or so? (assuming it's a few GB in size, never used Vayant, looking for it/the prices)
Or how to know when they changed? (currently using OTA_AirRulesLLSRQ, and it seems sometimes the rules change, while the BASIS / PRICE stays the same)